# Big gap in horizontal uicollectionview using orthogonalScrollingBehavior

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

As the title suggests I face weird bug (at least I did not expect that) where my items in my collection view have big gap like in this picture
[image]

I am using `orthogonalScrollingBehavior` from new `compositional layout` API
this is my code

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(100), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8)
        
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(200))
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
return section
```

I was expecting that the only gap between them is made by `contentInsets`. Please help if you know the answer or the reason why this happens

Comment: Is this also happening if you set your group widht dimension to absolute?  let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(100)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try to use widthDimension: .estimated(1) for the group
NSCollectionLayoutSize. Example:

```
func makeTestLayoutSection() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(400), heightDimension: .absolute(500)))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(1), heightDimension: .absolute(500)), subitems: [item])
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
    return section
}
```

Tested on tvOS 15.0

Answer (score 0):

same happening to me, maybe it's a bug since if visible cell widths are fitting the content width, then it does not get this annoying spacing. trying to find a workaround.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31856374)